# Craft install locally with MAMP Pro

Tags: mamp

Sorry to repeat this question but not yet found a fix:

Followed the install and when I try and navigate to:
site/admin

I get: "The requested URL /admin was not found on this server"
Have tried moving files around/permissions as 777, and changing the $craftpath but no joy as yet.
I use MAMP set up for other projects so is there an approach *without* changing MAMP settings?
Or am I missing something obvious?

Appreciate any help albeit a very basic question as want to get started!

Cheers

Comment: What happens if you go to `yourdomain.com/index.php?p=admin`?

Comment: Thanks, I get the "Could not find your craft/ folder…" alert – have tried various paths for $craftpath and changing directories, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? Sorry

Comment: When I create a new project with MAMP Pro e.g. craft/ the default index.php file MAMP creates loads fine with craft/ (i.e. craft.index.php) incase that indicates any issues or not

Comment: Have you seen [this guide](https://una.github.io/2013/08/13/the-absolute-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-craft-on-mac.html) to getting Craft running on MAMP?

Comment: Cheers, yes but will give another go

Comment: When we run local Craft installs on MAMP we run a folder called 'public' on the same level as craft/ (this is as the download comes) - this mirrors the set up on most live servers, and the default craft path and htaccess then works fine. You'd then access your admin panel at public/admin Also check the htaccess file in public is named '.htaccess' - easy to miss, as I think the default file in the downloaded public folder is named 'htaccess' (without the dot)

Answer (score 5):

When I'm trying to get past my initial errors, here are some of the things I try. This is assuming you have the usual directory setup, with the webroot `public` on the same level as `craft`

- Create `foo.html` in `public`, and visit `yourdomain.com/foo.html`. Good for mamp problems, virtual host problems, permissions problems.
- edit `public\index.php` and add `die('made it to index');` right at the top (after the `<php?`). Visit `yourdomain.com`. Good for some .htaccess problems.
- edit `public\index.php` and add `die('index is about to require '.$path);` right above the `require` at the bottom (and of course take out the earlier `die`). Make sure the craft path is right.
- edit `craft/app/index.php` and add `die('made it to craft/app/index');` right at the top. Can expose some php problems (open_basedir e.g.)

That's usually enough to get me started.

Comment: It was my MAMP Pro settings – needed to be Run Apache as home not www,

Answer (score 1):

Hope this video is useful for your query

https://youtu.be/rWHYTZEpa-M